# How to add a hyperlink to an existing word in a paragraph using Python-docx

Tags: hyperlink, python-docx, paragraph

0

Is there a way I can replace an existing word with a hyperlink, instead of paragraph._p.append(hyperlink)

I have to search for a place holder in the document and replace it with another text with a hyperlink to it. This 'append' adds the new text with a hyperlink beside the place holder. For instance, the place holder is 'Google Link', I want this to be replaced with 'Google' that has the hyperlink.

Appreciate your help.